# Background thread inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, dispatch-async

I have created a customise table cell in which i am downloading image in background thread in cell class and now suppose i moved to previous view controller. Would background thread still would execute and will crash the application. I could;t test this scenario as images loading fast and didn't get chance to move to previous view controller.

What would be the consequences?

Comment: Show the code you're using.

Comment: you can use Settings> developer> Network Link Conditioner > Very bad network to test on slow network . and on Mac too there is a tool for that with name "Network Link Conditioner"

Comment: As matt says in his answer, you can certainly write your code to handle this case without crashing. Test it yourself (using @hariszaman's suggestion, if need be) for crashes and report back. If it is crashing, edit your question to show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Problems can certainly arise if you don't do this correctly. You probably won't get a crash, because the NSURLSession prevents that for you by retaining its delegate. But by the same token, the view controller you have left will leak; it won't go out of existence, and the downloads and other things will continue to happen.

If you *are* doing it correctly, all downloads should be cancelled by you when the view controller goes out of existence. If you don't need these downloads occupying bandwidth and CPU time, you have a duty to call `invalidateAndCancel` to make that happen. Note that you generally cannot do this in the view controller's `deinit`, exactly because of the retain cycle. But once you have done it, your view controller will be able to go out of existence in good order.

Comment: thanks fir the reply. i'll post the code. But thats my question do i need to do something to cancel the download or it will cancel automatically when i move away from the controller.

Comment: And my answer is no it won't. Sorry if that wasn't clear. This is why you have been given `invalidateAndCancel`.

Comment: Expanded my answer.